# Select rows with minimum difference

Tags: sql

I'm pretty strong with SQL, but I can't think of good solution to this "look-alike" data analysis problem:

Given a table with a set of integers, I need to match each integer with the integer in a second table that is most similar (smallest absolute difference). Normally I'd do a Cartesian join and order by the difference in numbers, but I need to only get one pairing for each row from each table so no value from either table can be used twice.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

EDIT: Example:

TABLE_A

```
34
57
108
219
380
5000
```

TABLE_B

```
4000
200
400
99
40
33
34
4600
```

The pairing would be one row from table_a and the closest row from table_b:

RESULT

```
34,34
57,40
108,99
219,200
380,400
5000,4600
```

So no row from either table appears twice.

EDIT: more clarification: I'm trying to solve this problem where given 1 row from table_a, we find the 1 row from table_b that's closest. That becomes a pair and is removed. Then take the next row from table_a and repeat. So we're trying to find the best match for each row and optimize that pairing, not trying to optimize total differences.

Comment: "...one pariting for each row from each table..." is confusing. Is it "take every value in the first table and find the closest for it in the second table"? Or is there some requirements that every value in the second table must appear in the list, or otherwise must appear in the final set? Perhaps a small example would help

Comment: Can you add sample data please to help us visualise the inputs and outputs? Can we assume integers are unique in each table? What about 5 and 7 in one table, 6 in the other? 6 should appear twice because it is equally close to 5 and 7

Comment: If you're looking for the solution with a smallest total difference between sets, then if you have 5 and 8 in one table and 7 and 15 in the second table, then your sets would actually be (5,7), (8,15). This is true even though the smallest difference is between 7 and 8. Because ((7-5) + (15-8)) == 9 but ((8-7)+(15-5) == 11. So the solution that finds the closest number for that row isn't necessarily the optimal solution for the data set. We really need to know how you want to prioritize the solution and resolve conflicts/duplicates as gbn mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming

> where given 1 row from table_a, we find the 1 row from table_b that's closest

```
select
   *
from
   TABLE_A a
   cross apply
   (select top 1 Number from TABLE_B b order by abs(b.Number - a.Number)) b2
```

This also assume rows in b can be repeated: try it and see if it does what you want. However, this should fit your sample data so it would answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
select v.*
from

   (select a.value as avalue, b.value as bvalue,
   (abs(a.value - b.value)) as difference 
   from 
   TABLE_A a,
   TABLE_B b) v,

   (select a.value as avalue, b.value as bvalue,
   min((abs(a.value - b.value))) as difference 
   from 
   TABLE_A a,
   TABLE_B b
   group by a.value, b.value) m

where m.avalue = v.avalue and m.bvalue = v.value and m.difference = v.difference
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a cursor to handle this. Copy the data from each table to their own temp table and apply your logic one row at a time.

What makes this difficult, if not impossible without a cursor, is the fact that the order in which you handle each number from the first table will affect the end result.

If your first table looks like this

```
9
10
```

And your second table looks like this

```
5
6
```

Then your result will look like this if you process the 9 first

```
9,6
10,5
```

And the result would look like this if you processed the 10 first

```
10,6
9,5
```